# 'meta' extension for Markdown not loading in Python2.6?

Tags: python, markdown, meta

I'm trying to get the meta extension working with markdown in Python 2.6.
The code looks like this:

```
import markdown as m

print "Markdown version: ", m.version
file = "file.md"
md = m.Markdown( extensions = ['meta']) # doesn't complain
print "Registered extensions: ", md.registeredExtensions
text = open(file)
try:
    md.convert(file)
except AttributeError as a:
    print "Error: ", a
print "Meta: ", md.Meta
```

And my file looks like this:

```
Title: Chaleur
Date: 2010-07-11
Author: Gui13

Simple md test
![Chaleur](../content/chaleur.jpg)
```

What I'd like to get is something like `'title' : 'Chaleur', 'date' : '2010-07-11', 'author' : 'gui13'` when printing the `md.Meta`.

What I get is this:

> $ python test.py
>   Markdown version:  2.1.0
>   Registered extensions:  []
>   Meta:  {}

So it looks like the meta extension is not even loaded, whereas it should be (meta is supposed to be included in Markdown since version 2.0).

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`convert()` expects text. Replace `md.convert(file)` by `md.convert(open(file).read())`.

```
import markdown as m

print "Markdown version: ", m.version
file = "file.md"
md = m.Markdown(extensions=['meta']) # doesn't complain

print "Registered extensions: ", md.registeredExtensions
print "Preprocessors:", md.preprocessors.keys()
text = open(file).read()
try:
    print md.convert(text)
except AttributeError as a:
    print "Error: ", a
print "Meta: ", md.Meta
```

#### Output:

```
Markdown version:  2.1.0
Registered extensions:  []
Preprocessors: ['meta', 'html_block', 'reference']
<p>Simple md test
<img alt="Chaleur" src="../content/chaleur.jpg" /></p>
Meta:  {u'date': [u'2010-07-11'], u'author': [u'Gui13'], u'title': [u'Chaleur']}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved one of the issues, the latter one was the file encoding that I used: the markdown module will only process Unicode, whereas my files were a mix of UTF-8 and Latin encodings.